# Opening specific view from push notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have set up push notifications successfully on my app but I want the user to go to a certain view when the swipe the notification (iOS 5) opposed to just starting the app up.

The view controller is called statsViewController

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a custom dictionary to your push notification payload. See Apple's [push notification guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1). When you receive the notification, grab the payload and load the view controller based on what's inside.

Comment: Thanks! Found exactly what I was looking for in "The Notification Payload" section